# Dependency Injection on Blazor WASM (Client side)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor-client-side

I am trying to add the dependency injection in the Blazor WASM (client, asp-hosted application), but the C# class and it's interface are not found in the Program.cs (builder service).
The interesting part is that the other C# class/interface that I have only on the client side, works.
No, I did not to forget to include namespace, despite the fact that intelliSense does not recognize it.
Appreciate the help.

[image: Program.cs]

[image: Shared library]

[image: Client side]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post code as picture. Please use code formatting tools.

Comment: I don't see that interface and class in Shared, so why are you surprised they are not found?

Comment: If intellisense cannot find it and compilation fails, I think you probably did something wrong... we need a [mcve]

Comment: What's the namespace for `IDataService` and DataService and which project do they live in?  If all the namespaces are lined up, and projects referenced then intellisense should find them.  If not, then check that they are declared `public`.